# Why doesn't cornerRadius.width/2 give me a perfect circle?

Tags: swift, geometry, cornerradius

Im trying to create a circle from a squared view using this code:

```
self.situationerCircle.layer.cornerRadius = self.situationerCircle.frame.size.width/2.0
situationerCircle.clipsToBounds = true
```

But I still don't get a perfect round circle. I'm pretty certain it has something to do with my constraints as I did a test circle using these constraints:

[image: HERE]

with this code:

```
testc.layer.cornerRadius = self.testc.frame.size.width/2
testc.clipsToBounds = true
```

This works perfectly. The constraints for the bad circle however look like this:

[image: HERE]

The reason is because I want to make it grow in size in proportion to its container while keeping the same 1:1 ratio. But the result is a semi circle, that have subtle but visible edges. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I guess it because you apply the `cornerRadius` according to `width` too soon. Meaning that when you do it, the `width` it not yet the final one. Do it in `didLayoutSubview()`. You can check it by printing the width where you did it, and how it's rendered in `didLayoutSubview()`.

Comment: Awesome man, it worked! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to execute this codes in `viewDidLoad()` it might be happen. `viewDidAppear()` will work but if you are try inside the cell there is a method called `awakeFromNib()` where you define your objects. Add it and replace your codes there. And i agree with Larme answer you can call `layoutIfNeeded()` to refresh view and force perfect circle i think.